# Trying to count total orders, and unique monthly customers

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get total amount of orders, and the amount of unique customers in a 30 day timeframe.

I have this table:

order_id, order_date, order_country, customer_id.

```
(1, '2021/03/04', 'SWE', 1),
(2, '2021/03/01', 'SWE', 1),
(3, '2021/03/01', 'DK', 3),
(4, '2021/03/01', 'DK', 3),
(5, '2021/03/03', 'NOR', 2),
(6, '2021/02/27', 'DK', 3),
(7, '2020/12/30', 'Ger', 4);
```

I Have tried something like this:

```
SELECT order_date
     , COUNT(order_id) as orderAmount
     , COUNT(distinct customer_id) as customerAmount 
  FROM orders
 WHERE order_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() 
 GROUP 
    BY order_date
```

This gets the total amount of orders per date which is what i want. But it only counts unique customers per date and not monthly, so the same customer comes up multiple times. I have tried small variations of this sql script but can't quite get it to work.

Comment: What's missing from this question?

Comment: Can you illustrate the output you want based on the sample data

Comment: I want it to count the amount of orders everyday, and group them by the date, so the 2021/03/01 will be 3 and so on. I want it to do the same for customers, but only count customer once, even if the customer makes a purchase multiple times. So it should only count the customer the first date it appears.

Comment: @Rhazhin If that is what you want, then you should **edit** the question and actually say that, as well as show example output for the example input already shown in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check whether it's your desired answer or not.

**Schema (MySQL v5.5)**

```
create table orders (order_id int, order_date date, order_country varchar(10), customer_id int);
insert into orders values(1, '2021/03/04', 'SWE', 1);
insert into orders values(2, '2021/03/01', 'SWE', 1);
insert into orders values(3, '2021/03/01', 'DK', 3);
insert into orders values(4, '2021/03/01', 'DK', 3);
insert into orders values(5, '2021/03/03', 'NOR', 2);
insert into orders values(6, '2021/02/27', 'DK', 3);
insert into orders values(7, '2020/12/30', 'Ger', 4);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
      o.order_date,COUNT(order_id) as orderAmount
     , coalesce(max(Customer_Count),0) as customerAmount 
  FROM orders o left join (select order_date,count(distinct customer_id)Customer_Count from orders o where 
 not exists (select customer_id from orders oa where o.customer_id=oa.customer_id and oa.order_date<o.order_date
            and oa.order_date > now() - INTERVAL 30 DAY  )
 group by order_date) oc on o.order_date=oc.order_date
 WHERE o.order_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() 
 group by o.order_date
 order by o.order_date;
```

| order_date | orderAmount | customerAmount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-27 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-03-01 | 3 | 1 |
| 2021-03-03 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-03-04 | 1 | 0 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: You are most welcome. It's a nice problem to solve though I got you wrong in first try. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Just count the first time a customer appears:

```
SELECT order_date, COUNT(*) as num_orders,
       COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) as distinct_customers_on_day,
       SUM(SUM(seqnum = 1)) OVER (ORDER BY order_date) as running_distinct_customers
FROM (SELECT o.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY order_date) as seqnum
      FROM orders o
      WHERE o.order_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() 
     ) o
GROUP BY order_date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bbf2e32a999b472564236c2946d44a80) is a db<>fiddle.